# Binding source return -1 for BindingSource.Current

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm using binding source to provide data for data grid view.

```
bsActivities.DataSource = CurrentUser.Activities.ToList();

gvActivities.DataSource = bsActivities;
```

Now I want to delete item from it using index:

```
bsActivities.RemoveAt(bsActivities.IndexOf(bsActivities.Current))
```

It's strange to me that `bsActivities.Current` returns -1 even when data source is not empty, and there is item being selected. I also tried this to remove item from the binding source:

```
bsActivities.RemoveCurrent();

bsActivities.Remove(bsActivities.Current);
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It wasn't from the binding source or the list, it was from Equals method I overrode that returned wrong value, that was why the binding list couldn't find the object and always return -1.